# ActionController::UrlGenerationError using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller Posts in which I have a method:

```
def report_user
...
end
```

I have a view where I would like a link that will perform some logic (it should NOT actually take the user to a different page, only perform the logic and possibly show a dialog box after completion). The logic is contained in the report_user action in the Posts controller:

```
<%= link_to "Report User", :controller => :Posts, :action => :report_user %>
```

I would ultimately like to pass some variables also to the report_user action, however I haven't gotten that far as I've come across this error:

No route matches {:action=>"report_user", :controller=>"Posts"}

message << " missing required keys: #{missing_keys.sort.inspect}" unless missing_keys.empty?

```
    raise ActionController::UrlGenerationError, message
  end
```

I'm not sure what the issue is.  There is definitely an action in the Posts controller called report_user and it is not private. I'm not sure what the missing required keys means either. I've seen on SO other people with that error, but they all have routes defined that require parameters.  I do not have any routes defined for this. Possibly I"m going about the entire thing in the wrong way?

Comment: How have you defined that route in `config/routes.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nils suggested, you need an entry in routes.rb.  Assuming that this is a member route using a GET request, that entry would look like this.

```
resources :posts do
  get :report_user, on: :member
end
```

Next, you need to update your link to use the routing helpers that Rails provides.

```
<%= link_to "Report User", report_user_post_path(@post), remote: true %>
```

I included the remote: true option b/c you mentioned that clicking the link shouldn't reload the page.  The default response for this request will be app/views/posts/report_user.js.erb.

I would encourage you to read up on Rails routing at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.

Comment: thank you for your help.  I've read through the rupbyonrails guide many times but still not totally grasping the concepts.  I've implemented as you've said and now I get this error: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/posts/312/report_user") -- thanks again

Comment: I just re-read my answer and noticed that I led you astray with post :report_user instead of get :report_user.  Sorry.  I've updated my answer.  Can you please change your routes.rb entry to match and retry?